# What needs to be backed up for iOS developer identity?

Tags: ios

There were a bunch of files generated when I first started testing on a physical iOS device. I backed these three files up:

- CertificateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest
- developer_identity.cer
- Company_iOS.mobileprovision

I heard that once the certificate expires, you will get screwed if you don't backup the right files. Do I need to back up more files like my public/private key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to backup those files manually anymore. you can go to Xcode's Organizer (Window -> Organizer) and under Devices tab go to Developer Profile and hit Export. This will export your certificates, private keys and provisioning profiles to a single password-secured file you can later import.

And when your account expires you will be able to request new certificates and renew your provisioning profiles. Btw, if you ever lose any or all of this stuff, you can get them all back via the iOS Provisoning Portal, so don't worry too much about that and enjoy your development.